# string replacement on python

Tags: python-3.x, text, text-mining, text-processing

I want to change the first /E after /V to X and the second /E to Y and the third /E to Z in text files.

/V may be followed by a word other than /E

The number of /E is from 1 to 3.

For example, the following string

> AA/V+BB/E+CC/E+DD/E

should be changed as follows:

> AA/V+X+Y+Z

This is my code and the results are correct. But I think it's inefficient.

```
s1 = '1/VV+12/ER+123/EED+1234/EC'
s2 = 'GG/K+AA/V+BB/E+FF/E+CC/E'

for s in [s1, s2]:
    morphs = s.split('+')

    lst = []
    l = ['X','Y','Z']
    i = 0
    flag = False
    while i < len(morphs):
        lst.append(morphs[i])
        if '/V' in morphs[i]:
            for j in range(1, len(morphs)-i):
                if '/E' in morphs[i+j]:
                    lst.append(l.pop(0))
                    flag = True
                else:
                    lst.append(morphs[i+j])
                    i = i+j
                    flag = False
                    break
            if flag:
                break
        i+=1
    print('+'.join(lst))
```

Results:

1/VV+X+Y+Z

GG/K+AA/V+X+Y+Z

Comment: Why are also other chars that are not `/E` cahnged? What's the rule?

Comment: What happens to inbetween chars?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? What is your specific problem ? You need to explain more what issue you are facing. Currently it looks like you are asking people to do your job.

Comment: @vincrichaud I edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why `'AA/V+BB/E+FF/F+CC/E+DD/E'` should be `AA/V+X+FF/F+CC/E+DD/E` instead of `AA/V+X+FF/F+Y+Z`? I don't get it. Please rewrite/update your question, as it only mentions changing `/E` to `X`, `Y`, `Z`. There is not even a single word about these other letters and `+` signs present in the string.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way o do the same will be get the indices of `\v` and all the ,`\e` and then just check whether the indices of which e is more than that of V,
If it's so, then replace the E's accordingly as you said you can only have 1,2 or 3 E's in your text..

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement it in Python:

```
def format_string(s):
    start_index = s.index('/V')
    change_to = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
    for c in change_to:
        if '/E' in s:
            target_index = s.index('/E')
            if target_index>start_index:
                s = s[:target_index-2] + c + s[target_index + 2:]
    return s

s1 = 'AA/V+BB/E+CC/E+DD/E'
s2 = 'AA/V+BB/E+FF/F'
expected1 = 'AA/V+X+Y+Z'
expected2 = 'AA/V+X+FF/F'

print format_string(s1)==expected1
print format_string(s2)==expected2
```

Comment: When s = 'AA/V+BB/E+FF/F', the result should be 'AA/V+X+FF/F' because /V may be followed by a word other than /E as I mentioned above. But this code doesn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh, It works. But your code before edited didn't work. You added new line "if '/E' in s":. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I think I didn't explain my problem more specifically. /V, /E mean that they start with /V, /E. So /V can be /VA, /VVA and /E can be /EEC or /EE. I edited my code. Please refer to s1 and it's result. My code works. But I want to find more efficient way because I have a lot of data to convert.